# return %ROWTYPE from function PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I've tried to do following:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(id integer NOT NULL,
                         name character varying,
                         CONSTRAINT pk_table PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnmytable(inout p_rec mytable)
RETURNS mytable AS
$BODY$
declare
begin
p_rec.id := 1;--sequence 
  INSERT INTO mytable(id, 
                      name)
              VALUES (p_rec.id, 
                      p_rec.name);
end;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

---

```
do
$$
declare
  r_rec mytable%rowtype;
begin
 r_rec.name := 'Jorge';
 perform fnmytable(r_rec);
 raise notice 'OUT ID: %', r_rec.id;
end;
$$
```

> NOTICE: OUT ID: "NULL"

How to return the value of the sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use

```
SELECT * FROM fnmytable(r_rec) INTO r_rec;
```

I know that `INOUT` seems to suggest that the input parameter gets modified, but that is not the case. `(INOUT p_rec mytable)` is a shorthand for `(p_rec mytable) RETURNS mytable`.

Put differently, functions in PostgreSQL are always *pass by value* and not *pass by reference*.

Comment: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer : "(1, Jorge)"

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnmytable(inout p_rec mytable) AS
   --EDITED HERE
    $BODY$
    declare
    begin
    p_rec.id := 1;--sequence 
      INSERT INTO mytable(id, 
                          name)
                  VALUES (p_rec.id, 
                          p_rec.name);
    end;
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;
```

calling the function

```
do
$$
declare
  r_rec mytable%rowtype;
begin
 r_rec.name := 'Jorge';
 select * from fnmytable(r_rec) into r_rec;  --EDITED HERE
 raise notice 'OUT ID: %', r_rec.id;
end;
$$
```